# Удаление строки из таблицы

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью javascript по щелчку на кнопку "удалить" удалить строку из таблицы?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Имя</th>
      <th scope="col">Фамилия</th>
      <th scope="col">Username</th>
      <th scope="col">Очистить</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td><button>удалить</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
      <td><button>удалить</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td><button>удалить</button></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Ф-я, которая находи ближайший ряд и прячет его
function remove(){
  this.closest('tr').style.display = "none";
}

// Находим все кнопки
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

// Для каждой кнопки, когда её нашли вешаем ивент
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].addEventListener("click", remove, true);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Имя</th>
      <th scope="col">Фамилия</th>
      <th scope="col">Username</th>
      <th scope="col">Очистить</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td><button>удалить</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
      <td><button>удалить</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td><button>удалить</button></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: А если в таблице будут еще какие-то кнопки? Например, "добавить" "редактировать" и т.д., то как тогда быть? var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('button'); получается уже не подойдет ?

Comment: @АннаТот, тогда добавьте классы кнопкам удалить, например `<button class="delete">Удалить</button>`. И тогда уже в **js** `document.getElementsByClassName('delete')`. Либо второй вариант, в **html** сразу вешайте такое: `<button onclick="remove(this);">Удалить</button>` + в **js** `function remove(this) { тут то самое }`